# Does Apache Superset re-use dataset results for multiple charts or query it for every chart?

Tags: sql, apache-superset

I'm wondering about how Superset re-uses the dataset results already queried once. For example: you have a dataset `my_dataset` where there are 5 charts pointing to it with different views of the same raw data. If I put these 5 charts inside a dashboard and run it, will Superset execute a query just one time and all charts will use the same raw data? or will it execute the query from the dataset one time for each chart?

Also, there is a dataset type called `Virtual`. I didn't find any documentation talking about it, but I'm supposing that it could be something related to it...

My concern is: I want to avoid executing the same query multiple times for the same raw data, because by the end of the day what will really change it's just a view perspective of the same raw data.

Comment: Did you find the answer? seems like it does not, but maybe you learned more?

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing yet, still waiting from someone

Answer (score 4):

Superset is always sending a query to your database for each chart that it runs. Even when the charts are using the same dataset the query will be created based on chart configurations and then sent to your database.

This is because Superset is a consumption layer connected to your database, that doesn’t extract information from it - most of the processing/calculation is performed on the database level.

For Preset users, there is a Suggestion created for their Product team that you can vote for, to allow Preset to extract data from the database - this would allow it to perform additional calculations after the query is executed without consuming the DB again. The Idea is currently Gathering Interest of the community: [Extract data from the database to allow advanced analytics computation and save DB resources](https://preset.ideas.aha.io/ideas/PROD-I-3039)